# Drawing sine curve and curly bracket in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw the sine curve of the figure below [image]

in the left hand side of my diagram. The code I have written is given below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total=. 
{170mm,257mm},left=10mm,right=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[,line width=0.5mm,black,dotted](8,1.5) -- (8,6.5);
\draw[,line width=0.5mm,blue,->](0,0) -- (16,0);
\draw[line width=0.5mm,black,-](8,0.2) -- (8,-0.2);
\node at (8,-0.5) {$\frac{1}{2}$};
\draw[line width=0.5mm,black,-](10,0.2) -- (10,-0.2);
\node at (10,-0.5) {1};
\draw[line width=0.5mm,black,-](15.5,0.2) -- (15.5,-0.2);
\node at (15.5,-0.5) {$\infty$};
\node at (16.2,0) {$K$};
% drawing circles in right
\draw [red,fill=purple] (10,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [red,fill=purple] (10.5,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [dashed,thick,blue](10.25,5) ellipse (0.6 cm and 0.4 cm);
\draw [red,fill=purple] (12,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [red,fill=purple] (12.5,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [dashed,thick,blue](12.25,5) ellipse (0.6 cm and 0.4 cm);
\draw[,line width=0.5mm,black,-](9.0,5) -- (15.5,5);
\draw [red,fill=purple] (14,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [red,fill=purple] (14.5,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [dashed,thick,blue](14.25,5) ellipse (0.6 cm and 0.4 cm);
% draw circle in left
\draw [red,fill=purple] (1,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [red,fill=purple] (3,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [red,fill=purple] (5,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [red,fill=purple] (7,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw[,line width=0.5mm,black,-](0.5,5) -- (7.5,5);
% draw axis
\draw[,line width=0.5mm,black,->](0,1) -- (0,4);
\draw[,line width=0.5mm,black,->](0,1) -- (7.5,1);
\node at (0,4.2) {$\rho$};
\node at (7.7,1) {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Also, for the below **K** axis I would like to add a horizontal curly bracket between its endpoints at 1/2 and `$\infty$`. I am not quite sure these two things can be done. I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @ hpekristiansen. Thank you for pointing it out, I am updating the code.

Comment: Unrelated: You only need to use `-` and `black`, if you want to overwrite options given elsewhere. (`-` and `black` is default)

Comment: Unrelated: Try not to give line width explicitly unless needed - use `thick`, `ultra thick`, ...

Comment: Unrelated: Combine the tick marks and nodes into one command so that if you move one, the other automatically follows e.g. `\draw[thick](15.5,0.2) -- +(0,-0.4) node[below]{$\infty$};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=0.5mm,black,dotted](8,1.5) -- (8,6.5);
\draw[line width=0.5mm,blue,->](0,0) -- (16,0);
\draw[line width=0.5mm,black](8,0.2) -- (8,-0.2);
\node (half) at (8,-0.5) {$\frac{1}{2}$};
\draw[line width=0.5mm,black](10,0.2) -- (10,-0.2);
\node at (10,-0.5) {1};
\draw[line width=0.5mm,black](15.5,0.2) -- (15.5,-0.2);
\node (inf) at (15.5,-0.5) {$\infty$};
\node at (16.2,0) {$K$};
% drawing circles in right
\draw [red,fill=purple] (10,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [red,fill=purple] (10.5,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [dashed,thick,blue](10.25,5) ellipse (0.6 cm and 0.4 cm);
\draw [red,fill=purple] (12,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [red,fill=purple] (12.5,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [dashed,thick,blue](12.25,5) ellipse (0.6 cm and 0.4 cm);
\draw[,line width=0.5mm,black,-](9.0,5) -- (15.5,5);
\draw [red,fill=purple] (14,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [red,fill=purple] (14.5,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [dashed,thick,blue](14.25,5) ellipse (0.6 cm and 0.4 cm);
% draw circle in left
\draw [red,fill=purple] (1,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [red,fill=purple] (3,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [red,fill=purple] (5,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw [red,fill=purple] (7,5) circle [radius=0.25];
\draw[line width=0.5mm,black,-](0.5,5) -- (7.5,5);
% draw axis
\draw[line width=0.5mm,black,->](0,1) -- (0,4);
\draw[line width=0.5mm,black,->](0,1) -- (7.5,1);
\node at (0,4.2) {$\rho$};
\node at (7.7,1) {$x$};
\draw[thick] (1,4) cos +(0.5,-1.5) sin +(0.5,-1.5) cos +(0.5,1.5) sin +(0.5,1.5) cos +(0.5,-1.5) sin +(0.5,-1.5) cos +(0.5,1.5) sin +(0.5,1.5) cos +(0.5,-1.5) sin +(0.5,-1.5) cos +(0.5,1.5) sin +(0.5,1.5);
\draw[thick, decoration={brace, mirror, amplitude=10pt, raise=0.6cm}, decorate] (half.center) --node[below=1cm]{A brace} (inf.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A graph with lines, sine curve and a brace]

Comment: @ hpekristiansen, You are a magician, thank you very much!